C and C++ compiler include order and relative paths
I did a test with the following folder structure:
MainFolder
    main.cpp
    LibraryFile.h
    Files
        LibraryFile.h
    Library1Name
        MainHeader.h        
        LibraryFile.h
        Files
            LibraryFile.h
    Library2Name
        MainHeader.h
        LibraryFile.h
        Files
        LibraryFile.h

Let's assume the MainFolder (root) folder is in the include paths and nothing else.
Now, in main.cpp, I do:
#include "Library1Name/MainHeader.h"

Both MainHeader.h from Library1 and Library2 include:
#include "LibraryFile.h"
#include "Files/LibraryFile.h"

The point here is to create EXACTLY the same folder structure and names between all three versions:
The Library1 version
The Library2 version
The Root Folder version

As far as I can see, now there is a potential conflict between referring to those files within Library1, or, seeing as the main root folder is in the include paths, referring to the root version.
Question 1: Is the order here defined?
On my system, it picks the one inside Library1. So, there was no conflict. However, let's just say there IS a conflict, as I believe I had one earlier, what would be the effect of adding "./" as the include path?
For example, in main.cpp:
#include "Library1Name/MainHeader.h"

And then in Library1 MainHeader:
#include "./LibraryFile.h"
#include "./Files/LibraryFile.h"

From my test, when it did conflict (though I can't reproduce the conflict anymore), adding "./" solved the conflict.
My theory is that, if you do this, the compiler can't pick the root folder version, because you've specified "./" which specifically means relative to the very file in which you've written it. For clarification, "./" doesn't mean the folder path AFTER being included in a .cpp file, which would mean "THE LOCATION OF THE CPP FILE". Rather, it's ALWAYS referring to "THE LOCATION OF THE FILE IN WHICH "./" WAS WRITTEN. Which is the header file.
Question 2: Does "./" always do this?
Further, consider that we add path "MainFolder/Library2Name" to the include path. This would mean we introduce ANOTHER conflict, but, as I said earlier, specifying "./" eliminates all conflicts.
To what extent am I right?
Also, there are differences between #include "" and #include <>, but as this is really complicated, let's forget <> and focus on "". The test I did is here.

Relative path includes are brittle and not recommended. A language laywer tag would probably get a more proper answer. Otherwise, even though the question tries hard to avoid it, this will invite opinion-based responses. Do you "wild west" it, include & src, pitchfork, Canonical Project Structure (not associated with Canonical of Ubuntu fame, also recommends never using "" includes). I also agree that ignoring <> includes is hand-wavey at best and detrimental to what I think are the types of answers expected.

Everything in this says this is done in an implementation defined manner so you really need to check your compiler documentation.  Personally, just be explicit and use the full path name.

@sweenish "A language laywer tag would probably get a more proper answer.": All of this is implementation-defined, except that you must use </> for standard library headers to work correctly. The standards don't even require a file system to be present.

Even though it's to a different question, A: What is the difference between #include  and #include "filename"? covers the key point: implementation-defined (there is not even a guarantee of searching the current directory, only "typically"). To determine "To what extent am I right?" you would need to specify your implementation (and drop "language-lawyer"). That being said, it is possible that gcc, clang, and MSVC have similar behavior; I don't know.

@NathanOliver "check your compiler documentation" - I'd rather do it in a standardised/defined way. People are saying don't use "" at all. OK, so assuming I use < > instead of "", the question still stands, what does <./> do and is it standard/defined?

There isn't a standard defined way.  The standard says how this happens is up to the implementation.  So that's where you have to look.

@NathanOliver Hmm, the don't use "" philosophy is weird, it's everywhere. I just saw it in ASIO.

@Zebrafish It is not at all standardized and isn't even required to be supported. The complete header file lookup behavior is non-standardized (except that the standard library headers must work in their correct form with angle brackets). Usually relative paths are not used and a build system is used instead that can be told in which paths to look for headers. The build system is then implemented to support as many implementations as required.

@Zebrafish I never said don't use "".

@user17732522 Good info. And that probably suffices as an answer to this question.

Presuming that you don't feature both Library1 and Library2 in the same build artifact, I would be looking to use the build system to direct the visibility of included files, setting include paths as necessary.  That also simplifies things if you decide to move entire folder structures without needing to tweak paths in dozens of source files.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp

All of this is implementation specific. In rough terms, if you use relative paths in an #include, specify an absolute path (e.g. via -I /usr/you/include on the command line if using gcc, suitable options in makefile to ensure every source file is provide consistent options). Resolving of relative paths will then consider candidates relative to that absolute path.  So, when compiling the libraries, use -I /wherever/MainFolder/Library1Name (not -I MainFolder) so source files for that library that #include "LibraryFile.h" will include /wherever/MainFolder/Library1Name/LibraryFile.h

POSIX c17 identifies what is expected in POSIX systems.  But (as others have identified), the behaviour is implementation defined.

All of this is implementation defined. To be specific ([cpp.include]/1-3):


A #include directive shall identify a header or source file that can be processed by the implementation.
A preprocessing directive of the form
# include < h-char-sequence > new-line
searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the < and > delimiters, and causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the header. How the places are specified or the header identified is implementation-defined.
A preprocessing directive of the form
# include " q-char-sequence " new-line
causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the " delimiters. The named source file is searched for in an implementation-defined manner. If this search is not supported, or if the search fails, the directive is reprocessed as if it read
# include < h-char-sequence > new-line
with the identical contained sequence (including > characters, if any) from the original directive.


[emphasis added]
So almost everything about where searching is done, in what order, etc., is implementation defined. There's only really one fairly simple rule: something like #include "foo" has to search all the same places as #include <foo> would, but possibly some more besides--and if there is any "more besides", those places take priority.
Beyond that, it's all up to the compiler.

Thank you. That addresses the first part of my question. How about "./"? So if "" isn't supported it uses <>, so I'm wondering what <./> does. Well, nothing standardised apparently, it's implementation-defined. OK.

@Zebrafish: Yes--the starting point for any particular search, or even whether . means "current directory" or "/" is a directory separator are all implementation defined. Even if we stick to typical systems (MacOS, Windows, Linux, *BSD) something like #include "./foo.h" might easily vary (e.g., if you specify an include directory with -I, and a header in that directory includes another header with #include "./foo.h" does that mean it will only search in that directory? That's up to the compiler.
